# Google Chrome network inspector - How do I search for one or more strings in URLs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

One web page makes two api calls which end like this /element /updateObject. If I want to filter only /element, then I enter that in the filter box. But, how do I filter only those call urls which contain /element or /updateObject ?

Comment: Use regexp syntax: `/\/(element|updateObject)/`

Comment: @wOxxOm - Could you please add your comment as an answer with an explanation for that regex. Thank you. Chenqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by wOxxOm works - `/\/(element|updateObject)/`. We can use regular expressions to search.